# Oracle - How to return average from a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I need to select employees having salary bigger than the average salary grouped by departments.

```
SELECT * FROM employees
WHERE salary > (SELECT AVG(salary), department_id FROM employees GROUP BY department_id)
```

It's failing because It returns me 2 columns.

I have tried with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
HAVING salary > AVG(salary)
GROUP BY (department_id)
```

Now i am getting error message: **ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression**

Answer (score 3):

The simplest cross-database approach would be to use a JOIN:

```
SELECT employees.*
FROM employees
JOIN ( SELECT department_id, AVG(salary) avgSalary
       FROM employees
       GROUP BY department_id) departmentSalaries
  ON employees.department_id = departmentSalaries.department_id
  AND employees.salary > departmentSalaries.avgSalary
```

The most efficient approach for Oracle would be to use an analytic function (aka window function):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT e.*, AVG(e.salary) OVER ( PARTITION BY e.department_id ) as avgSalary
  FROM employees e) t
WHERE salary > avgSalary
```